# Years ago, this was the password for our firewall

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

I picked this password because it proclaimed a warning one should never, ever ignore, assuming they could discern the meaning:

```
!p/V+-###
```

So what sentence of warning does this string of characters state?

*Before anyone says anything, I will concede that I never said that it was a particularly secure password, especially for a firewall! (I hope they've changed it since then! I has been 20 years.)*

Comment: What's the puzzle?

Comment: I guess the password is !P/v+-###

Comment: Sorry that it wasn’t clear. I hope that sentence improves it.

Comment: Is the "one" who the warning is intended for the administrator of the firewall, or someone trying to access/penetrate it?

Comment: The warning was intended for anyone who would try to.. ahem... "mess" with the firewall.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is an even longer shot:

> Don't pee on the electric fence. Or, don't pee on electric fences.

Because:

> !p = don't pee;
>  / = on (over);
>  V+- = electricity, volts positive and negative;
>  ### looks like a fence.

Comment: You, my new friend, are the winner! You have been awarded one mighty space donut with extra frosting for having it **exactly** right on the first stab. Nice job!

Comment: I might actually pull some old ones out to see if the meaning can be conveyed, but I fear someone with some amazing AI will render my thinking into a moderately complex Bayesian network and hack all my bank accounts.
Again, thanks for playing!

Comment: LOL your brain works in weird ways!

Comment: This might come as a shock, but you are not the first person who's told me this.

Answer (score 3):

This is a long shot, but I think the warning is:

> **Not powerful or fast enough to tolerate hashes**

potentially describing some quirk of the firewall, because:

> The ! operator can be read as '**not**' in some programming languages
>  The P symbol represents **power** in physics
>  The / can be read as **OR**
>  The v symbol represents **velocity** in physics
>  +- (or more specifically ±) is used to represent **tolerances**
>  # is called a **hash** symbol in computing

I could be *way* off base with this guess as well.

Comment: I really like how you think, but I am afraid the mindset behind this was much less disciplined. Also, I realize that I made a **MISTAKE** so I will edit and let you have another go.

The best hint is that it starts out being very cut and try with the symbolic meaning, but then becomes more abstract at the end.

Comment: I will say that you have at least one thing correct.

Comment: With your correction in place, I think shoover's interpretation is better than any I can come up with!

Comment: Yes, I admit my mistake probably fouled up your chances, but don't worry, there are plenty of space donuts to go around.

Comment: unfortunately space donuts are all hole.

Comment: Ssh, that’s the secret!